# EJB 2.1 Web Service End Point @WebContext

Tags: java, web-services, soap, ejb, ejb-2.x

I have a WSDL file which defines an event operation.

Need to define a **SOAP web service end point** which is called by a third-party with some parameters as specified in a WSDL file.

The project uses **EJB 2.1**

Can´t get the end point to work (404 error):

```
http://localhost:28080/myapp/ws/ClassCallBack
```

The classes below are inside a JAR file included in the root folder of the EAR file.

Is there anything wrong ? 
Do I have to declare this class as an EJB in some xml? (in ejb-jar.xml , all EJB Session Beans are declared, but this is not a session bean)

```
@WebService
public interface ClassCallBackWs {

@WebMethod
  public void event(@WebParam(name = "event") ClassParameter event) 
      throws Exception;      
}

=====================================

@Stateless(name = "ClassCallBackEjb")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@WebService(name = "ClassCallBackWs", portName = "ClassCallBackWs",
        serviceName = "ClassCallBackWsService",
        targetNamespace = "http://test.serverurl.org.com/",
        endpointInterface = "ClassCallBackWs")
@WebContext(contextRoot = "/myapp/ws/", 
            urlPattern = "/v0/ClassCallBackWsImpl", 
            transportGuarantee = "NONE", secureWSDLAccess = false)
public class ClassCallBackWsImpl implements ClassCallBackWs {

    @WebMethod
    public void event(@WebParam(name = "event") ClassParameter event) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give below an example of one possible solution. 
Created a custom servlet which has a mapping to the implementation class by defining a JAX WS end point in its XML

(Have concealed all names relating to the final solution, as is private-owned. Sorry if there is a mistake because of this).

**Servlet mapping / XML:**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myapp/ws/v0/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

XML configuration for the servlet used as End Point:

```
    <jaxws:endpoint
        id="CallBackWs" implementor="org.test.ClassCallBackWsImpl "
        wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/wsdl/CallBackTest.wsdl"
        address="/ClassCallBackWsImpl"
        bindingUri="ClassCallBackWsImpl">
    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

**End point Impl Class:**

```
   @WebService(
      portName = "CallBackWs",
      serviceName = "CallBackWsService", 
      targetNamespace = "http://test.server.callback.ws/", 
      endpointInterface = "org.test.CallBackWs") 
   public class ClassCallBackWsImpl implements ClassCallBackWs{    
       public void event(ClassParameter event) throws Exception { 
       } 
   }
```

**Interface class:**

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://test.server.callback.ws/", name = "ClassCallBackWs")
public interface Ws {
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "event", targetNamespace = "http://test.server.callback.ws/", className = "org.test.ClassParameter")
    @WebMethod
    public void event(
        @WebParam(name = "event", targetNamespace = "")
        org.test.ClassParameter event
    ) throws Exception;
}
```